# C++ Invalid conversion from interface class to child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to solve this problem but I don't know how to make conversion from interface class to my child class. Basicly, I am trying to make array of Vehicle pointers and elements of array to be child classes pointers, then pass element by element to Counter class method which will calculate value of total passengers, but I get compiler error:

```
invalid conversion from 'oss:Vehicle*' to 'oss::Bike*' [-fPermissive]
```

Here is my code:

**Vehicle.h**

```
using namespace std;

namespace oss{

class Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual string type() = 0;
    virtual unsigned passengers() = 0;
    virtual ~Vehicle();
};

class Land_vehicle : public Vehicle{
protected:
    string typeOfVehicle;
    unsigned numberOfPassengers;
public:
    Land_vehicle();
    string type();
};

class Bike : public Land_vehicle{
public:
    Bike();
    unsigned passengers();
};

class Counter{
private:
    int totalPassengers;
public:
    Counter();
    void add(Bike*b);
    int total();
};
```

**Vehicle.cpp**

```
using namespace oss;

Vehicle::~Vehicle(){};

Land_vehicle::Land_vehicle(){typeOfVehicle = "Land";}
string Land_vehicle::type(){return typeOfVehicle;}

Bike::Bike(){numberOfPassengers = 1;}
unsigned Bike::passengers(){return numberOfPassengers;}

Counter::Counter(){totalPassengers = 0;}

void Counter::add(Bike b){
    cout <<"inside add bike"<<endl;
    totalPassengers += b.passengers();
}
int Counter::total(){return totalPassengers;}
```

Main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
using namespace oss;

int main()
{
    Counter c;
    Vehicle* v[] = {new Bike};

    size_t sz = sizeof v/sizeof v[0];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        c.add(v[i]);

    std::cout << "Total: " << c.total() << " passengers!" << std::endl;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        delete v[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On which line is the error reported?

Comment: You've defined `add` to take objects by value, yet you're passing pointers to it. That's not going to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You define `Vehicle* v[]` but then have `v.size()`, which isn't going to work... The error message also doesn't match the code you provided.

Comment: Edited code for clarity

Comment: Where / what is class Counter?  code missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your classes, every `Bike` and every `Car` are `Vehicules. THis is why, whenever you need a` Vehicle*`, you can use as well a` Bike*`or a`Car*`.

You make use of this in your assignment:

```
Vehicle* v[] = {new Bike};   // yes a Bike* can be converted to a Vehicle*
```

However the reverse relation is not true.  Not every `Vehicle` is necessary a `Bike`.  This is why you can't just use a `Vehicle*` when you need a `Bike*`.  To do the reverse condition you first have to check that the `Vehicle` you're working with is indeed a `Bike`, and if it's the case you can use casting.

Fortunately, your classes are polymorphic (due to the virtual functions).  So you have to use a `dynamic_cast()` to convert from parent (base) pointer to child (derived) pointer. But take care to check that the conversion succeeds (i.e. casted pointer isn't null).

### What's wrong here ?

You experience this and related problems, when you try to add a vehicle to your counter:

```
    c.add(v[i]);   // v[i] is a pointer to a vehicle, but which one
```

In fact there are several problems with your `Counter::add()` :

- first, you have a plain object as argument, not a pointer.  This means that you'd need to dereference the pointer with `c.add(*v[i])`.  But the overload require that you tell at compile time which type of object it is (i.e. there's no `add(Vehicle)`, and if there would be one, you'd suffer from object slicing)
- then, if you'd use a pointer instead of a plain object,  you could use casting:  `c.add(dynamic_cast<Bike*>(v[i]);`
- finally,  you'll realize that even with casting, you have a problem:  in your example you vow that there's only a bike in your array.  But in real code, you couldn't now for sure.

### First work around

Now putting this together, here is how to modify your loop to add to the counter only bikes:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    if (dynamic_cast<Bike*>(v[i]))
        c.add(dynamic_cast<Bike*>(v[i]));
}
```

THis suppose to change the signature of add to:

```
void Counter::add(Bike* b){
    cout <<"inside add bike"<<endl;
    totalPassengers += b->passengers();
}
```

Here a **[live demo](http://ideone.com/h5v6NR)**

### And a solution

If you have polymorphic classes, it's a pitty not to benefit from polymorphism:

```
class Counter {
    int totalPassengers;
public:
    Counter();
    void add(Vehicle* b);
    int total();
};
```

And the implementation of the redesigned function:

```
void Counter::add(Vehicle* b){
    totalPassengers += b->passengers();
}
```

And this will work whatever the number of classes you derive from vehicle ! No longer need to add  dozens of similar overloads of the same function.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/ol83IG)

Comment: Can you give me example how to use it in my program ? I googled, but I still don't know how to use it in my add function...

Comment: @Teemo  I've edited my answer after having had a closer look at wwhat you try to do in Counter::add().  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, meanwhile I figured out how to fix problem on my own, but thanks to your hint about dynamic_cast. Your answer really helped me, and now I understand some things better. Thank you!

Comment: I just added checking if dynamic_cast is valid for every vehicle type in my add function instead to call it in for loop, and it works fine. Rest of code is identical like yours.